# AuthorizationCodeReceived session is null

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

based on sample msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp and also created Web Project by Visual Studio 2017 
https://github.com/hannespreishuber/demoAuthorizationCodeReceivedSessionNull
my issue is that Session in ctx is null on

```
 AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        var ctx = context.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase;
```

in the MSgraph sample - the same Code have a session object - Take a look at my GitHub repository for Details.
My guess is, that AuthorizationCodeReceived is executed in a diffrent Kind of context (thread?) and context is wrong.

Comment: There are many discrepancies between your configuration and the standard example. As you said, the result of the test should be Owin validation has a problem. The suggestion still starts with the example, not completely written by yourself, familiar with it and write it yourself.

Comment: it seems ASP.NET FriendlyUrl makes a Redirect an destroys the session context for owin